# Is there a way to add some padding to an artboard an action?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am doing the following action to automate Object->Artboards-> Fit to artwork bounds.
The problem is the designs look kind of ugly with the artboard so close to the edges. Is there another action I can automate that can add like a 30px padding to any size artboard that is encountered?  I want to resize the artboard to fit but then add some padding so its not to tight.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach-

Select all on your artboard

Object> Group

Object> Path> Offset Path

Set offset to 30 px

Set Fill and Stroke to None

Then do Object> Artboards> Fit to Artwork Bounds